# What do [hash Headers] and [hash Totals] calculate in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to sum up a series of numbers based on whether they are green or not.
So I first used
`SUMIF(Elec[Green (Y/N)],"Yes",Elec[[#Headers],[Total (kWh)]])`, but this gives the wrong answer (100),

and then I tried `SUMIF(Elec[Green (Y/N)],"Yes",Elec[[#Totals],[Total (kWh)]])`, it also gives the wrong answer  (11,110).

Then I finally realised that `SUMIF(Elec[Green (Y/N)],"Yes",Elec[Total (kWh)])` gives the correct answer. But this brings the question, how is formula 1 and 2 calculated?

Here's my calculation sheet (Tab name "Calcs"):[image: Tab name "Calcs"]

And my data tab (Tab name "Elec"):

[image: (Tab name "Elec")]

Comment: The first formula selects the header as criteria range and not the actual range in the `Structured reference table` --> `SUMIF(Elec[Green (Y/N)],"Yes",Elec[[#Headers],[Total (kWh)]])` the second one, includes the total cell `=SUMIF(Elec[Green (Y/N)],"Yes",Elec[[#Totals],[Total (kWh)]])` While the third one has actually taken the ranges from the table `=SUMIF(Elec[Green (Y/N)],"Yes",Elec[Total (kWh)])` if you enter each of those formulas in a cell and press function key `F2` you will realize what the formulas have selected for ranges

Comment: Sorry it should be sum range instead of criteria range in the comments above. Try evaluating the formula, you will know the reason, it is not selecting the SUM range for the third param of `SUMIF()`

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya Thanks for the explanation. But I 'm still courious about how did it get the answer 11,100. Any ideas? :)

Comment: 11,100 or 11,110 which one?

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya 11,110. Curious about how this is calculated. Thanks.

Comment: Because you have used the `Totals` row there

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya Sorry, my bad. I don't understand the result given by the first formula (results=100). Any ideas? :)

Comment: Try evaluating formula. Learn how to evaluate **[here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/evaluate-a-nested-formula-one-step-at-a-time-59a201ae-d1dc-4b15-8586-a70aa409b8a7#:~:text=1%20Select%20the%20cell%20that%20you%20want%20to,of%20the%20formula%20has%20been%20evaluated.%20See%20More.)**

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya I tried, doesn't gives a reasonable explanation really :(

Comment: You have already pointed out the difference between the values returned. `SUMIF(Elec[Green (Y/N)],"Yes",Elec[[#Headers],[Total (kWh)]])` this formula which was returning 100 because it selected headers as sum range

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya I'm more confused now. I thought the header is a text not a number? Also, why only 100? It's a "No", why doesn't it summ up the number with a "Yes"?

Comment: May be someone has reasonable insight for your question, however i dont find any reason to keep thinking about which really don't make sense, while the `SUMIF()` clearly states in taking criteria range, criteria and sum range. While you have not selected any. Sorry mate you may wait for others, who will be interested in giving you a hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The help for SUMIF says:

> **Sum_range**  should be the same size and shape as range. If it isn't,
> performance may suffer, and the formula will sum a range of cells that
> starts with the first cell in sum_range but has the same dimensions as
> range.

The important bit here is *the formula will sum a range of cells that starts with the first cell in sum_range but has the same dimensions as range*

So in your case the *range* is `A2:A5` and the *sum_range* is `A1:A4`.

The first item in *range* is `Yes` and the first item in *sum_range* is text so is either translated to 0 or ignored (not sure which).
The third item in *range* is `Yes` and the third item in *sum_range* is 100.